# Distinct network subnet masks

Tags: networking, tcp

I understand that 192.168.1.0/24 & 10.0.0.0/24 are distinct networks however are the following also distinct networks?

- 10.0.0.0/24 & 10.0.8.0/24
- 10.0.0.0/8 & 10.0.8.0/24

I have a LAN using 10.0.0.0/8 connected via a VPN tunnel using 10.0.8.0/24 and I would like to know if the two are seen as distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have overlapping subnets, like `10.0.0.0/8` and `10.0.8.0/24` in your example. One application of this is to split a subnet asymmetrically so that the majority of addresses in the subnet is behind one interface of a router, and a smaller subnet behind the other interface. The mechanism behind this is called [Longest Prefix Match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_prefix_match), and works because the routing table can have more than one route that matches a destination address.

The routes in the routing table are searched from "most specific" (with the longest matching network part) to "least specific", and the route that matches first is chosen. Routing tables typically always contain overlapping entries, since they usually specify a default route. The default route always matches, but a more specific matching entry is always preferred over the default route.

If the subnets are "distinct" is a matter of terminology, but for practical purposes they are as distinct as non-overlapping subnets.

Answer (score 1):

10.0.0.0/24 & 10.0.8.0/24 are separate networks.

```
10.0.0.0/24 is from 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.255
10.0.8.0/24 is from 10.0.8.0 to 10.0.8.255
```

10.0.0.0/8 & 10.0.8.0/24 are not. 10.0.8.0/24 falls within the range of 10.0.0/8, which is from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255